# In C, how to initialise an array with a certain pattern?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to initialise an array in C following a pattern. 
For example, here are two arrays with 10 elements. Each array have following elements: {0,0,2,3,0,7,0,1,9,0}
And here is my code: Note: example above and code below are not related, just to elaborate the definition of "pattern" in my case.

```
void CreateArray()
{
  int i = ArraySize();
  int j;
  int k = Rand_Gen(); 
  printf("%d\n",i);
    int array[i];
    for (j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
    if (k>0 && k<=30)
    {
      array[j]=4;
      array[j+2]=23;
      array[j+5]=900;
      printf("%d",array[j]);
    }
    else if (k>30 && k<=60)
    {
      array[j]=2;
      array[j+3]=54;
      array[j+5]=870;
      printf("%d",array[j]);
    }
    else 
    {
      array[j]=0;
      printf("%d",array[j]);
    }
    }
}
```

However, after running this program, I can only get an array with the same element. In this case, half of the time I get an array filled with 4 only, and half of the time I get 2. 
I have done Googling but I could not find a possible solution to my problem. Or, maybe my method to print elements of the array is not correct? 
Thanks first.

Follow up: 
I have tried adding "int k = Rand_Gen()" within loop, but I still can only get one number. Here is the update segment of code:

```
void CreateArray()
{
  int i = ArraySize();
  int j;
  printf("%d\n",i);
    int array[i];
    for (j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
    int k = Rand_Gen(); 
    //some if statements here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code exhibits undefined behaviour, since it accesses `array` outside its bounds. Step through the code in your debugger and the mistakes should then be obvious.

Comment: If you are accessing j+n in the loop, then j should increment by n before going to the next element

Comment: @Paul R But when compiling code, there is no error message, and running the program does not report "out of bound" error or alike.

Comment: C has no run-time checks - it's a fairly low level language - it's up to you, the programmer, to write correct code.

Comment: @PaulR Oh, thanks. So C is powerful but programmer needs to pay extra attention on the programming.

Comment: Yes, that's right - higher level languages tend to give you more protection from programming errors, but there is usually a performance cost for this.

Answer (score 3):

- You use :

  ```
  int k = Rand_Gen();
  ```

  ***outside*** your `for` loop. This means that `k` will only be created once.  Consequently, your `for` loop will be executed `i` times with the same value of `k` and therefore it will be entering the same part of your `if-else` statement. You need to generate `k` ***inside*** your loop.
- Another issue is that your index 'j' gets out of your array bounds. In particular, your loop runs as following :

  ```
  for (j=0;j<i;j++)
  ```

  At some point, `j` will reach value `i-1` (which will be the last iteration). At this point, your `if` and your `else if` parts try to access the positions `array[j+2]`, `array[j+3]` and `array[j+5]`.

  However, you have declared `array` to be of size `i` so the statements :

  ```
  array[j+2] = ... ;
  array[j+3] = ... ;
  array[j+5] = ... ;
  ```

  with `j` being `i-1` will be equivalent to :

  ```
  array[i+1] = ... ;
  array[i+2] = ... ;
  array[i+4] = ... ;
  ```

  which is definetely indexing out of bounds.

Comment: Then how to generate a value in j+2 when j+2 is still within the bound? Could this be something like array[j+2], or other formats?

Comment: @白崎つぐみ I did not understand your question. Could you please clarify?

Comment: My thought is: I want to create an array with 0 scattered inside all elements, like my example shows, or something like {0,0,2,0,3,4,0,0,5}. And I need to write code to put numbers into those positions filled with non-zero values. But a simple for loop will fill the array with either all zeros or all non-zero values.

Comment: @白崎つぐみ One idea is to first fill your array with numbers and then, in a `for` loop, fill the places you want with zeros. How about that?

Comment: But what if I want to fill more than one number? Like, I want to create multiple arrays like {0,0,2,0,3,0}. Should I need to create multiple for loops, and each for loop fills certain locations with certain numbers?

Comment: @白崎つぐみ Let me ask you something. Do you know the exact positions where you want to put your zeros? Or your numbers? In other words, do you know which positions must contain a zero/a number?

Comment: Strictly speaking, I don't know where should I put numbers or zeros, because I am asked to put numbers randomly. But for test purpose, I can assume where I should put number and where I should put zero.

Answer (score 2):

Move  `k = Rand_Gen();` inside for loop.

Currently you are generating 'k' value only once.

Also accessing `j+2` index make out of bound access.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I didn't realise this.